# Out of Date Vine Leaves - are they safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, vacuum

I bought vacuum packed vine leaves quite some time ago. Stupidly didn't get round to using them so they are still in the fridge. They are well passed their sell by date of March 2011. Should I just bin them or do you think they are still fine to use? I think they look okay...

Thanks very much for your help!

Kate

Comment: Probably won't kill you, but veggie matter, like leaves in water, gets  soggier over time. They may now lack the integrity to form proper Dolmatas.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and for answering so quickly. That makes very good sense. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

They may be safe but they are certainly not guaranteed to be safe. see [How long can I store a food in the pantry, refrigerator, or freezer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer).

Besides safety they have likely lost all consistency and won't taste well. You're propensity to prevent food waste is admirable, in this case however, it's best to bin them or better yet, compost them in a flowerpot (if they're not in acid or something).

Comment: Thanks for making me chuckle! D'you know, it was the novelty of seeing them in our local Deli that got me excited... then of course, I never rose to the challenge. I think you're right about ditching them at this stage. Thank you very much. :)